# Insert picture file, using variable, into text in .HTMLBody

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I'm trying to use a variable to insert an image in an e-mail.

```
With OutlookItm
    .To = strTo
    .CC = strCc
    .Subject = strSubject
    .HTMLBody = "Hello all, <p>In attach the <b>Filtered Trunk Report</b> and below the <b>Invoice Volume chart</b>:</p>" & _
    "<center><img src = Filename:ChartFile1 ></center>" & "<p>.</p>" & _
    "<center><img src = 'C:\Users\matuo\OneDrive\Desktop\Chart2.jpg'></center>" & Signature
    .Display
End With
```

The code works for "Chart2.jpg", but I want to use a variable for the directory and file.

The picture using the variable doesn't work.

Comment: See how you're using `&` operators to concatenate parts of the string literal? Everything between `"` characters is a string literal, so you need to replace the hard-coded path in `<img src='C:\Users\matuo\OneDrive\Desktop\Chart2.jpg'` with a concatenation of the variable's value like `<img src='" & thePathVariable & "'>"`, and above that you would declare the variable with `Dim thePathVariable As String` and assign it to the result of a function that prompts the user for a file name, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Let's image you have got a string object `pathToImage` which contains the image path, in that case the code may look like:

```
With OutlookItm
    .To = strTo
    .CC = strCc
    .Subject = strSubject
    .HTMLBody = "Hello all, <p>In attach the <b>Filtered Trunk Report</b> and below the <b>Invoice Volume chart</b>:</p>" & _
    "<center><img src = " & pathToImage & " ></center>" & "<p>.</p>" & _
    "<center><img src = 'C:\Users\matuo\OneDrive\Desktop\Chart2.jpg'></center>" & Signature
    .Display
End With
```

However, a local path to image is not really a good idea. Such images will not be displayed on the recipient side because the image itself is stored on your machine. Most probably you'd need to embed an image to the email itself. To get that done you need to attach the image file and set several properties - they are actually optional, even the following code works fine:

```
.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\JoeSchmo\Pictures\imageName.jpg", olByValue, 0
.HTMLBody = "<BODY><IMG src=""cid:imageName.jpg"" width=200> </BODY>"
```

But ideally you'd need to set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` and `PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN` properties. For example:

```
Function SendasAttachment(fName As String)
 
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachments
 
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olMsg = olApp.CreateItem(0) ' email
Set olAtt = olMsg.Attachments
 
Const PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001E"
Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"
Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B"

' attach file
olAtt.Add (fldName & fName)

Set l_Attach = olAtt.Add(fldName & fName)
Set oPA = l_Attach.PropertyAccessor
       oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG, "image/jpeg"
       oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "myident"
       oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN, True
       
olMsg.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8514000B", True

olMsg.To = "test@email.com"
msgHTMLBody = "<HTML>" & _
                   "<head>" & _
                   "</head>" & _
                   "<BODY>" & "Hi " & olMsg.To & ", <br /><br /> I have attached " & fName & " as you requested." & _
                   "<br /><img align=baseline border=1 hspace=0 src=cid:myident width='400'/>" & _
                   "</BODY></HTML>"
' send message
With olMsg
  .Subject = "Here's that file you wanted"
  .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
  .HTMLBody = msgHTMLBody
  .Save
  '.Display
  .Send
End With

End Function
```

Read more about that in the [Embed Images in New Messages using a Macro](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/embed-images-messages-macro/) article.

Comment: Thanks! I used the command
.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\JoeSchmo\Pictures\imageName.jpg", olByValue, 0
.HTMLBody = "<BODY><IMG src=""cid:imageName.jpg"" width=200> </BODY>"

It worked!